# Let $p_i\in(0,1)$, upper bound $\max_{i=1,...,n} \left( |\frac{1}{p_i} - \frac{1}{p_i^2}|\right)$ in terms of $\min_{i=1,...,n} (p_i)$.

Tags: inequality

Let $p_i\in(0,1)$, upper bound $\max_{i=1,...,n} \left( |\frac{1}{p_i} - \frac{1}{p_i^2}|\right)$ in terms of  $\min_{i=1,...,n} (p_i)$ or ($\max_{i=1,...,n} (p_i)$).

Here is what I have tried, and I'm wondering if there is any other way to make a tighter bound. Or if there is other insights I missed.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\max _{i=1,...,n}\left(|\frac{1}{p_i}-\frac{1}{p_i^2}|\right)
& =\max _{i=1,...,n} \frac{1}{p_i}\left(|1-\frac{1}{p_i}|\right) \\
& =\max _{i=1,...,n} \frac{1}{p_i}\left(|\frac{p_i}{p_i}-\frac{1}{p_i}|\right) \\
& =\max _{i=1,...,n} \frac{1}{p_i} \frac{|p_i-1|}{p_i} \\
& =\max _{i=1,...,n} \frac{|p_i-1|}{p_i^2}\\
& \le \frac{\max _{i=1,...,n}|1-p_i|}{\min _{i=1,...,n}p_i^2}\\
& \le \frac{1-\min _{i=1,...,n}p_i}{(\min _{i=1,...,n}p_i)^2}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** :

The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x}$ is positive for all $x \in (0,1)$ and also decreasing (as its derivarive $f'(x) = (x-2)/x^3$ is negative).

Then

$$\begin{align}
\max_{i=1,...,n} \left( \left|\frac{1}{p_i} - \frac{1}{p_i^2}  \right|\right) &= \max_{i=1,...,n} \left( \frac{1}{p_i^2} - \frac{1}{p_i}    \right) \\
&= \max_{i=1,...,n} \left( f(p_i) \right) \\
&=f(\min_{i=1,...,n}p_i) &\\
&= \frac{1}{(\min_{i=1,...,n}p_i)^2} - \frac{1}{\min_{i=1,...,n}p_i} 
\end{align}$$

*Remark*: The result is a strict equality.